# Problems lifting up state in React

Tags: reactjs, lifting

I'm writing a web app in React.js 18, and I've got an issue that I thought I could fix with lifting state, but it's not working.

The site functions to add polls on a topic. When I create a poll in my  page, the list of polls on the  page doesn't update until I do a refresh. I've tried lifting the state, but either I'm not doing it correctly or I'm having an asynchronous issue.

Here is the relevant code:

Here is in App.tsx:

```
function App() {
  const [newPoll, setNewPoll] = useState(0);

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home polls={samplePolls} />} />
          <Route
            path="/login"
            element={
              Auth.loggedIn() ? (
                <Navigate to="/" replace={true} />
              ) : (
                <Login setLogIn={setLoggedIn} />
              )
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/:username/:pollname"
            element={
              <Poll
                loggedin={loggedIn}
                currUser={userInfo.username}
              />
            }
          />
          <Route path="/:username" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route
            path="/create"
            element={
              !Auth.loggedIn() ? (
                <Navigate to="/" replace={true} />
              ) : (
                <Create updateList={setNewPoll} currentList={newPoll} />
              )
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/polls"
            element={<Directory uvotes={userInfo.votes} newPoll={newPoll} />}
          />
          <Route path="*" element={<Home polls={samplePolls} />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

The state `newPoll` and `setNewPoll` is the lifted state. I pass `setNewPoll` to the `<Create />` page, and I pass `newPoll` to the `<Directory />`

Within `<Create />`, here is the quiz creation handler:

```
const handleCreate = async () => {
    // handler for submission of quiz to be created

    try {
      const { data } = await addPoll({
        variables: {
          ...
        },
      });
      updateList(currentList + 1);
      navigate(data.addPoll.redirect);
    } catch (err: any) {
      ( error handling is here )
    }
  };
```

Within `<Directory />`, I have this:

```
export function Directory({ uvotes, newPoll }: directoryProps) {
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(QUERY_ALL_POLLS, {
    variables: { ... },
  });

  const list = data?.getPolls.polls || false;

  return (
    <section id="directory" className={pollCount.created.toString()}>
      <ul>
        {list
          ? list.map((poll: userPollProps, index: number) => {
              return <PollListing key={index} index={index} poll={poll} />;
            })
          : ""}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```

So what I thought I was doing, was creating the state at the App level, handing the setting function to the creation function, handing the state value to the directory function, and on creation of the new poll I set the state to an essentially arbitrary value. What I expect is that immediately after creating the new poll, that if I go to the directory the new poll will be there...and it is not.

I also tried using Recoil.js, subscribing both pages to the atom, and arbitrarily changing the atom on creation...and that also didn't work.

Is there something I'm missing? Or is there a different and more relevant technique I should be using?

Comment: I don't see `newPoll` used anywhere within `Directory`. I expect it's maybe used as a variable in `useQuery()`, but can you show that? If not, where are you expecting that state that you passed down to be consumed? As an aside, the use of multiple terms ("quiz", "poll", "list") to refer what seems to be the same thing only adds to the confusion for me as a reader

Comment: @Codebling: That is something I'm a little confused about. I don't NEED anything to happen besides a re-rendering of the directory. I don't even need the value of newPoll to be used: I just need the page to re-render.

I take your issue with the naming: once I get to a stable place I think some renaming is in order. Thanks for that critique!

Comment: Oh, I see! That looks like it should be enough to trigger a re-render. State lifting looks fine. Have you checked (e.g. with React Dev Tools) to see that the state is indeed changing?

Comment: @Codebling: I will check tomorrow, going to sit down with a clearer head and go over everything with a fine-tooth comb. Or a fine tooth comb. I like my tooth combs to be better than average. ;)

Comment: @Codebling: I've done some more digging. Here is a clarification. This directory page is NOT being shown concurrently with the create poll page. I go to the directory page, I see the list, I go to create a poll, I return to the directory page and the list is unchanged. In my code snippet above, you can see that the first thing the directory page is supposed to do is to make a call to the database for the current list...I can confirm that the server is NOT getting that call after the first page load. For some reason the React page is not making subsequent calls without a reload.

Comment: More info: After I create a poll the app automatically redirects the user to that poll's page. If I visit the polls page after that the new poll is not there. I can navigate from page to page via the main nav with no update to the polls page. BUT if I click on a poll title (that is, go somewhere not via the main nav) on the directory page and then come back, then the directory IS updated. Perhaps its react-router that is at issue?

Comment: `react-router` could conceivably be causing issues, hard to say. I would suggest removing it and trimming down your code to basically only the problematic code, and hopefully it will be easier to debug. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue wasn't with react-router, or with state lifting, but with caching. I was able to find [documentation for refetching queries in Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#refetching-queries), and this worked well. One can define specific queries to be re-run following specific mutations in specific React components. Here I've done so with the ADD_POLL mutation in the create component:

```
const [addPoll] = useMutation(ADD_POLL, {
    refetchQueries: [QUERY_ALL_POLLS],
  });
```